# Console+Windows' form

Tags: c++, windows, forms, console

Are there winAPI function (without classes) to create a daughter window from console application. It necessary to print graphics of shapes on window, and input commands to console.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

it's simpler to create console window for your GUI application. [Have a look here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/mfcconsole.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you mean something specific by "daughter", but it's certainly possible for a console application to create a window (or as many as it likes). It's also possible for a windowed application to allocate a console.

Allocating a console from a windowed program is theoretically a bit work, but does have one advantage: you can write the majority of your windowing "stuff" using an application framework of your choice (Qt, wxWidgets, etc.)

If you work directly with the Windows API, it's a bit easier to create a console application and create windows as you see fit. About all you have to do in this case is write your code just as you normally would a windowed program, but instead of `WinMain`, name your entry function `main`. Based on that, the linker will automatically set the "console" flag in the executable, and Windows will give it a console when it starts up. The big advantage here is that C++ standard library gets initialized automatically, so things like `cin` all work without any extra effort on your part. If you start from a Windowed program and allocate a console, all that'll work by default will be the Windows API functions (`ReadConsoleInput`, `WriteConsoleOutput`, `ReadFile`, `WriteFile`, etc.) You *can* get the C and C++ functions to work, but you have to deal with some fairly poorly documented areas (that are all open to change with the next release of the compiler) to make it happen. I'd *generally* avoid this unless I was only going to use the Windows API functions to deal with the console anyway.

Comment: @Jerry: your comment about `main` versus `WinMain` assumes the Microsoft toolchain. e.g. GNU toolchain is happy with any of those two, and doesn't use C++ statup function as hint about subsystem. it's just that way by default with the MS toolchain. But even with MS's toolchain you can use any of the 4 MS startup functions with any Windows subsystem, by specifying the (machine code level) entry point. please don't teach folks here that `WinMain` has any practical use, except to avoid a little typing in build commands or project config with MS toolchain. Rest of answer very good, as always. :-)

Comment: @Alf: I thought about that, but based on the "form" tag, considered the MS toolchain a reasonable simplifying assumption. You could well be right that my judgement on that score was less than perfect though. Thanks for the kind comments otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I did it this way. How can I send message to worm to out put graphics - I try SendMessage(Hwnd,WM_DESTROY,0,0) for example, but nothing work.

Comment: linked doesn't deduce the type of application based on `WinMain` or `main` presence. ther's a Linker->System->SubSystem flag for this in Visual C++: `Windows` or `Console` (`/SUBSYSTEM` linker option)

Comment: @Andy T: MS' linker has a switch, but it also (tries to) figure out the value for the switch based on presence of `main`, `WinMain` or `DllMain` (or `wmain`, etc.) You can use the switch to override that, or to specify the subsystem if you don't use any of the above.

Comment: @Jerry: tnx, didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much easier way that may work well for you, provided you're using Visual Studio:

If you are, you can start a forms application by creating a forms project, add the necessary forms, and then change the application type (by right-clicking the project and selecting properties) and changing it to a console application.  It will still spawn the form windows as you would expect, but will also start a Console window (which will still be populated by cout, etc...)!